# Inequality involving $\sin$: step in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

I am reading a prove of a proposition in a textbook and in a step of it the author establishes the following inequality considering the $x$ is near $0$ (and I don't know pretty well how can be justified):

$$|x^2-\sin^2x|<x^4$$

I know that for $x$ near $0$, we have that $x^2\geq\sin^2x$ but I don't know how to continue really (I am sure it is easy but I don't figure it out) Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint : Calculate the taylor series of $\sin^2(x)$ and estimate the remainder of order $4$

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$$
2\sin^2x=1-\cos(2x)=\frac{(2x)^2}2-\frac{(2x)^4}{24}+\frac{(2x)^6}{6!}+...
$$
This is an alternating series where consecutive terms have a quotient
$$
\frac{(2x)^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}.
$$
Thus the quotient sequence is falling, and once if falls below $1$, also the sequence of the absolute values of the terms falls. Now apply the limit estimate for alternating series to get
$$
0\le x^2-\sin^2x \le \frac{x^4}{3}~~\text{for}~~ x^2<3
$$
or taking the next terms into account
$$
\frac{x^4}3-\frac{2x^6}{ 45}\le x^2-\sin^2x 
\le \frac{x^4}3-\frac{2x^6}{ 45}+\frac{x^8}{315}~~\text{for}~~ x^2<\frac{15}2
$$

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hopital's Rule $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac {\sin t-t+t^{2}} {t^{2}}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac {\cos t-1+2t} {2t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {2-\sin t} 2=1$. Hence, $\frac {\sin t-t+t^{2}} {t^{2}} >0$ for $|t|$ sufficiently small.  Put $t=x^{2}$ to get your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Without loss of generality, $x > 0.$

Taylor Series for $\sin(x)$ is

$$x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots - \cdots.$$

Using the Liebniz rule for alternating series,

you have that

$$[x + \sin(x)] < 2x \tag1 $$

and

$$[x - \sin(x)] < \frac{x^3}{3!}. \tag2 $$

Taking the product of (1) and (2) gives you the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

By the AM-GM inequality on $1$ and $(1-x^2)$, where $0<x<1$, we have
$$\sqrt{1\cdot (1-x^2)}\le \frac{1+(1-x^2)}{2}
\\
x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\le x\left(1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)
\\
\sqrt{x^{2}-x^{4}}\le x-\frac{x^{3}}{2}<x-\frac{x^{3}}{6}<\sin x$$

where the very last inequality is well-known or may be proven as in Jack D'Aurizio's answer to [MSE Q1948951](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949190/161490). We square both sides and then treat the case of negative $x$ by symmetry to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @Peter. Consider the Taylor expansion of the of the function $f(x)=\sin^2(x)$ of order 4 around $x_0=0$. We have that:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&\approx f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)+(x-x_0)^2\frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}
+(x-x_0)^3\frac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}
+(x-x_0)^4\frac{f''''(x_0)}{4!}\\
&=x^2-\frac{x^4}{6}.\\
\end{align}
$$

This means that for $x$ close to $x_0=0$ we have that:

$$
|x^2-\sin^2x|\approx|x^4/6|\leq x^4 \text{ for all $x$.}
$$